# Creating subdomains with Index.php

Tags: php, apache, indexing, subdomain, frontend

Forgive the newb question, but I've looked and couldn't find an explanation for what I'm trying to achieve. I have an Index.php file routing all urls on our corporate site, for example:

```
// this routes all of our subdomains
if (!in_array($sub, Array('www', 'localhost:9998'))){
switch ($sub) {
    case 'landingpage': // landing.domain.com
        include 'landing/landingpage.php';
        break;
    case 'faq': // faq.domain.com
        include 'landing/faq.php';
        break;
    }
}
```

Now I need to create a clean url with a subdomain and slashes, ie:

```
 clientname.domain.com/employee/login
```

I've tried the following, with a file named employee-login.php in a "clientname" folder, but no success. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
    case 'clientname':
        $ext = substr(strrchr($url[0], '.'), 1);
        if (empty($url[0])) {
            include 'clientname/'.$sub.'.php';
        }
        else {
            check404('clientname/'.$sub.'-'.$url[0].'.php');
        }
        break;
    default:
        check404('clientname/'.basename($sub).'.php');
        break;
```

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?

Comment: @Nerdwood no, I tried a few variations of the above (turns out we dont use htaccess anymore for our site) and no luck.

Comment: It is still an open issue for you? You might need to start a new question if it is!  ;)